# Loop iteration. JavaScript console image

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm new to Javascript and super new to stackoverflow so here's a question I've been wrapping my head around for a couple of days. 
I've got a homework to do, a console application that prints "M" on the console which is made of asterisk's:"*" and surrounded by minuses:"-", they act as the space.
Character's width is given as N.
However as you can see from my code below, I've managed to do only half of it as I can't seem to figure out how to print the other part of the character, opposite to the current.
Sorry for the messy code and explanation as I am pretty new to programming altogether. Please give me some good advise on how to proceed with my logic for the code.

```js
var newArr = [3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
let N = Number(newArr[0]);
console.log(`N = ${N}`);
let str = '';
let j = '';
let k = ''

if (N > 2 && N < 10000) {

  for (var i = '-'; i.length <= N + 1; i += '-') {
    str += '*';
    if (j.length <= N * 5) {
      for (j = ''; j.length <= N * 5; j += '-') {
        if (j.length >= N && j.length < N * 2) {
          j += str.repeat(N);

        } else if (j.length >= N * 3.5 && j.length < N * 4) {
          j += str.repeat(N)
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(i + j)

  }

}
```

This is how it should look:

```
N = 3
---***---***---     
--*****-*****--       
-***-*****-***-      
***---***---***
```

```
N = 5
-----*****-----*****–––––-----*****-----*****–––––
----*******---*******--------*******---*******----
---*********-*********------*********-*********---
--*****-*********-*****----*****-*********-*****--
-*****---*******---*****--*****---*******---*****-
*****-----*****–----**********-----*****–----*****

N = 7
-------*******-------*******--------------*******-------*******-------
––––––*********-----*********––––––––––––*********-----*********––––––
-----***********---***********----------***********---***********-----
----*************-*************--------*************-*************----
---*******-*************-*******------*******-*************-*******---
--*******---***********---*******----*******---***********---*******--
-*******-----*********-----*******--*******-----*********-----*******-
*******-------*******-------**************-------*******-------*******
```

Comment: please use self explanatory variable names instead of pseudo-minified style. it makes reading it much less tedious for everyone.

Comment: How should it look like for N = 5 and N = 7 ?

Comment: How do you want your output to be different than it is?

Comment: I can't wrap my head on how to structure the algorithm and cross 2 more columns of asterisks with the current ones, so that an "M" is formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I can give you some clues.

In general you need **1 parent loop** defined as **ROW** which prints each row of M and nested loop(s) defined as **COL** used to concatenate the result with '*' or '-'.

```
for (let row = n; row >= 0; row -= 1)
```

inside ROW you need if else construction to check the row number and you have to check if you are at the top of the M or at the bottom i.e **you have to divide the M to 2 parts**, **TOP** and **BOTTOM**.

Inside ROW **you need nested loop(s)** defined as **COL** so you can concatenate the result using **COL**

In short in each nested loop you have to concatenate result += '*' or '-';
and on each row you have to concatenate result += '\r\n' i.e **new line**.

TOP part is:

```
---***---***---     
--*****-*****--
```

BOTTOM part is:

```
-***-*****-***-      
***---***---***
```

so you have **if (top) else (bottom)** logic

Inside TOP/BOTTOM logic *you have to figure out the pattern* i.e **how many stars/dashes you have** and **how they incrase/decrease on each ROW**.

Some variables which can help you:

```
const n = 7;
const middle = Math.ceil(n / 2);
let  asterisksTopLength = n;
let asterisksBottomLength = n - 1;
let dashesBottomLength = 1;
let dashesTopLength = n;
let result = '';
```

HINT: You need to change dashes/asterisks variables on each ROW inside TOP/BOTTOM if else body

Try also to divide the task to a few small tasks. i.e try to find out how to print firstly the dashes i.e

```
---
--
-
```

then how to concatenate the dashes above with '*' so they became

```
---***
--*****
-***
```

etc...

BTW there is a solution without nested loops i.e using only 1 loop and like you have figured out string.repeat(), but I believe that your task is to practice nested loops so you have to avoid .repeat().

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful post! I will wrap my ahead around your idea and try to solve it that way as mine seems to be with inadequate logic.

Comment: If your deadline is close to the end I can share both solutions, drop a line if you wish so, till then try to solve it.

Comment: Yes, it's kind of soon - tomorrow. Could you share a solution?

Comment: Here you go: gist.github.com/idmitrov/2e38aab8bab56868232abc60b97b7dfd
It uses a lot of nested loops which I believe is just to practice em, however there are greater solutions without so many loops.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a great code. Easy to read and understand!